# Using Shortcuts / Function keys with 2 keys combination

Tags: openbravo

Our business requirement is to have faster data entry with minimum usage of mouse. We like to have all process buttons/custom window to be activated using 2 keys combination or Function keys. By default, openbravo allows ctrl+alt+shift+ initial character but it is not very swift.

Pl advise.

regards,

Usman

Comment: And... so your question being...?

Comment: as your using browser for openbravo, already many shortcuts are being used by the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this document for shortcut keys in openbravo

https://docs.google.com/a/saksham-india.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2gMmM8Z0eQdEpfNHNLX3I5Z0RhUVFiU0VXckxMalE&usp=drive_web#gid=0

```
Grid
Select all    Alt+Shift+A
Unselect all    Alt+Shift+N 
Jump to column filters  Ctrl+Shift+F
Returns to grid while keeping the filter value.     Esc
Clear column filters    Alt+Del
Disable implicit filters    Alt+Shift+Del
Insert row  Ctrl+i
Delete row  Del
Edit row    F2
Switch to form view (while editing) Ctrl+F2
Open row (into form view)   Enter
Execute process (orange buttons)    Ctrl+Alt+Shift+<Letter>
Cancel editing  Esc

Generic 
Jump to workspace tab   Alt+Shift+1
Jump to sibling tab to the left Alt+Shift+ArrowLeft or Ctrl+Space+ArrowLeft
Jump to sibling tab to the right    Alt+Shift+ArrowRight or Ctrl+Space+ArrowRight
Jump to parent tab  Alt+Shift+ArrowUp or Ctrl+Space+ArrowUp
Jump to child tab   Alt+Shift+ArrowDown or Ctrl+Space+ArrowDown
Close active tab    Alt+Shift+W
Cancel (former undo)    Esc
reload (refresh)    Ctrl+Shift+R
Export  Ctrl+Shift+E
Print   Ctrl+Shift+P
Copy record (clone) Ctrl+Shift+K
Email   Ctrl+Shift+M
Show audit trail    Ctrl+Shift+Y
Deep link (url) Ctrl+Shift+U
Launch attachments (add) dialog Ctrl+Shift+A
Quick Create    Ctrl+Q
Quick Launch    Ctrl+O
*Application menu   Ctrl+M
Alerts  F8
Help    Ctrl+H
User/profile menu   Ctrl+P
Logout  Ctrl+Alt+Shift+End

Form    
Open dropdown   Alt+ArrowDown
Open selector   Ctrl+Enter
Open on tab ("link out")    Ctrl+Alt+Enter
Maximize or restore form view   Alt+Shift+Enter
Save & Close    Ctrl+Shift+X
Close (same as X top-right icon)    Esc
Next record Alt+Shift+PageUp
Previous record Alt+Shift+PageDown
First record    Alt+Shift+Home
Last record Alt+Shift+End
Delete  Ctrl+Del
Save    Ctrl+S
New record in form view Ctrl+D

Popup   
Close (same as X top-right icon)    Esc
Maximize or restore the popup   Alt+Shift+Enter
```